# Cant view my .ASP pages in my browser

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

I am learning to code .asp and am trying to set up a local environment for me to test simple asp codes.

I have just installed IIS on my PC running windows 10.

My browser successfully loads "localhost"

I have pasted the following code with the filename of test.html into the inetpub/wwwroot ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%
Response.Write("Hello World!")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Navigating to localhost/test.html  works fine.

Now, I want to change the file extension from test.html to test.asp. After i had done this, my browser is not able to load localhost/test.asp  at all. It shows the following error,

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

I am expecting the webpage to display "Hello World!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ASP** is legacy **ASP.NET**. I believe what you want is to use ASP.NET therefore name your file:

*test*.**aspx**

I don't think you want to try technology from 18 years ago but if that were your case, you will need to activate this feature Windows 10. In order to do this you will have to go to Windows Components and features and enable this old feature here:

[image]

Comment: I am glad I could help. If this post helped you please do not forget to mark this as your answer